# how to work with a class instance inside the viewController in Appdelegate?

Tags: ios, instance, viewcontroller, appdelegate

i have an class instance and it methods in my ViewController.
Is it possible to get access of this instance and methods in the appdelegate ?

its like:

```
@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize myObject;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myObject = [[myObject alloc] initWithFrame:........];
    [self.view addSubview:myObject];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [myObject doSomething];
}
```

and I want to call the same method in AppDelegate

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [myObject do Something];
}
```

Someone an idea ?

greetz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the controller from `rootViewConroller` like this and call the fucntion of it

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{ 

     UIViewController *controller = self.window.rootViewController;

     if([controller isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]){
           FirstViewController *firstViewController;

            for (id vc in [((UINavigationController*)controller) viewControllers])
             {
                 if ([vc isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]])
                 {
                     [((FirstViewController *) vc) doSomething];
                     break;
                 }
             }
     }
     else if([controller isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]]){
             [((FirstViewController *) controller) doSomething];

     }else{
        //Not found
     }
}
```

Comment: if you know you `rootViewController` as `FirstViewController` than you can skip if part just write else part.But this code will not break in future

Comment: your welcome if it works than accept this solution it will help others